# compilation error with MPI_type_create_resized in Fortran 90

Tags: compiler-construction, mpi, intel, fortran90

I need to scatter a 2D array with non-contiguous blocks in a Fortran 90 code. The code need to call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED to change the bounds and extend of the new vector type before calling MPI_SCATTER. The compiler I use is Intel XE 12.1.

When using the Intel MPI, the code compiles well but with a warning message, which I don't think it should be there:

```
mpiifort -c test.f90
test.f90(21): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [EXTENT]
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(oldtype, 1, extent, newtype, ierr)
-----------------------------------------^
```

When using the OpenMPI, the compilation terminates with an error:

```
mpif90 -c test.f90 
test.f90(21): error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED]
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(oldtype, 1, extent, newtype, ierr)
-----^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

Is this a bug in OpenMPI? Does anybody know how to fix it? Thanks.

The test code is pasted below:

```
program test
!
USE MPI
implicit none
!
integer :: numprocs, ierr, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer ::  rows, cols
integer :: typesize, extent, oldtype, newtype
!=============================================================
!
call MPI_INIT( ierr )
call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr )
!
cols = 8
!
rows = cols
!
call MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(cols, rows/numprocs, rows, MPI_REAL8, oldtype, ierr) 
call MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_REAL8, typesize, ierr)
extent = rows/numprocs*typesize
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(oldtype, 1, extent, newtype, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(newtype, ierr)
!
call MPI_TYPE_FREE(oldtype, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_FREE(newtype, ierr)
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

stop
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the compiler being picky about the types of arguments, which is a good thing; lower bound and extent here have to be integers of kind `MPI_ADDRESS_KIND`.   So this works:

```
program test
!
USE MPI
implicit none
!
integer :: numprocs, ierr, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer ::  rows, cols, typesize
integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: lb, extent
integer :: oldtype, newtype
!=============================================================
!
call MPI_INIT( ierr )
call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr )
!
cols = 8
!
rows = cols
!
call MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(cols, rows/numprocs, rows, MPI_REAL8, oldtype, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_REAL8, typesize, ierr)
extent = rows/numprocs*typesize
lb = 1
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(oldtype, lb, extent, newtype, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(newtype, ierr)
!
call MPI_TYPE_FREE(oldtype, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_FREE(newtype, ierr)
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

stop
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. This fixed the warning message from the Intel MPI. Do you know how to fix the error message from the OpenMPI? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's the same cause; the above works fine for me with openmpi v1.4.4 and 1.6.4 with intel compilers as well as intel mpi.

Comment: I still get the same error after the change. I tested with openmpi v1.4.3 and v1.6.0. The error complains about not matching subroutine for MPI_type_create_resized, which is very strange.

Comment: Jonathan, I didn't change the constant of the lower bound. After I changed that, it fixed the error. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just for clarity, the reason the compiler couldn't match the subroutine is because it can't find a version of the subroutine with the appropriate types of arguments.  OpenMPI's fortran bindings are fussier about this than IntelMPI's, which in general is a good thing even if it can be annoying at times.